# Is it possible to search for index of multi type ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, mvvm-light

I plan to get the specified indexes of multiple items within the collection and populate a GUI. Can this be done with ObservableCollection methods or will other ways need to be explored? Also using MVVM Light toolkit.

I start with 6 properties:

```
ObservableCollection<Model> collection = new ObservableCollection();

Public Class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string _Item1;
    public string Item1 
    {
        get{ return _Item1;}
        set{ Item1 = value; RaisedPropertyChange(nameof(Item1));
    }

    private int _Item2;
    public int Item2 
    {
        get{ return _Item2;}
        set{ Item1 = value; RaisedPropertyChange(nameof(Item2));
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Being new to MVVM, I'm not sure where to start on how to get the specific item at a specified index. Would I use LINQ methods?

```
 Where(i => i.Item1[SpecifiedIndex?]);
```

Example:

```
Output: Collection Index 1:Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4. 
Output: Collection Index 2:Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4. 
Output: Collection Index 3:Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4.
```

I'm stuck on how to get the items out of the collection in order. I've added them and if I use a Foreach loop I'm capable of returning all items such the depicted output. However, I do not need all of them to print. I need the items at a given index.

Comment: So you just need Item1 through Item4 on some specific index?

Comment: question not clear, what do you want 'index' to do? can you replace with some meaningful variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is. Your Where makes no sense; how do you index an integer?

Anyway, `collection[specifiedIndex].Item1` gets you the `Item1` value from the object in the collection at that index. If that's what you're asking.

If you want all collection items where `Item1 == 9`,

```
var x = collection.Where(item => item.Item1 == 9);
```

I mean, it's just a collection. Like a List, but it also happens to raise notifications.

Comment: I had only read up on "Where" and wasn't sure how to use it but this definitely works! Thanks Ed!